# react-select - Show different text/label for drop-down and Control?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In my react-select drop-down, the labels are hundreds of characters long. In the Control chips, I would like to show a shorter version of what's in the drop-down. Is this possible?

Edit: I want to set the text of the chip, not pixel width.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

You can custom the style of the control chips when using the multiple value `Select` with the props `styles` like the following example:

```
const customStyles = {

    multiValue: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
     // set all chips to a maximum of 100 pixels
      maxWidth: "100px"
    })
  };
```

[Here a live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xpvyo667vz) of shorter versions of long label. I put special (and ugly) background so you can see where each container starts and ends.

**SOLUTION 2**

Following the comment request this is an alternative solution to cut the selected option. You can overwrite the component `MultiValue` with the prop `components`. Inside this component you will have access to the option label and apply `substring` function to truncate the label as short as you can.

```
const MultiValue = props => {
// truncate the string to 3 characters
   const content = props.children.substring(0, 3);
   return <components.MultiValue {...props}>{content}...</components.MultiValue>;
};
```

[Here a live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3r88r3jx6q) of this alternative option.

**SOLUTION 3**

In the same idea as the solution 2 if you know in advance your option labels and the crop you want to display you can set an extra props in your `options` array like this:

```
const options = [
  {
    label:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi augue sem, bibendum quis mollis amet.",
    // you can name this new prop has you want
    chipLabel: "Lorem ipsum",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    label:
      "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.",
    chipLabel: "Sed ut perspiciatis",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    label:
      "Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?",
    chipLabel: "Ut enim",
    value: "3"
  }
];
```

And then overwrite the component with the following code:

```
const MultiValue = props => (
  <components.MultiValue {...props}>
    {props.data.chipLabel}
  </components.MultiValue>
);

<Select options={options} components={{ MultiValue }} />
```

[Here a live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/znxjxj556l).

**SOLUTION FOR SINGLE VALUE**

If you want to display a different value than in options for `SingleValue` select I recommend to use the solution 3 and change the component like this:

```
const SingleValue = props => (
  <components.SingleValue {...props}>
    {props.data.chipLabel}
  </components.SingleValue>
);

<Select options={options} components={{ SingleValue }} />
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5w60l5qmx).

Comment: Thanks so much for the live example.

I want to set the text of the chip, not pixel width. Is that possible?

Comment: @Melissa if not pixel width do you want it in percent ?

Comment: For example, I want to show `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` in drop-down, and `abc` in chip.

Comment: Like limit string at 3 characters ?

Comment: Thanks so much for responding.  
  
In your live example, the chip is "Opt...". I don't want the ellipsis.  
  
Here's an example of what I want.  
  
Option 1. Drop-down "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit". Chip "Lorem ipsum"  
  
Option 2. Drop-down "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium". Chip "Sed ut perspiciatis"  
  
Option 3. Drop-down "Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?". Chip "Ut enim".

Comment: @Melissa so if I get you right there no logic in the crop that you want. Will you know in advance what crop will have each options ?

Comment: Correct, there is no logic. For each option, I know in advance 1) the long text I want for drop-down, 2) the short text I want for the chip.

Comment: @Melissa I have posted a third solution to match your requirements

Comment: Any idea on how to do the exact same thing, but for single-value mode? Based on your Solution 3, I would expect to simply change 'components.MultiValue' to 'components.SingleValue', but it doesn't work. It's just ignored. Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @JimOtt replacing the component should as in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5w60l5qmx) if not I recommend you to create a new question with your code to debug

Answer (score 0):

In React-select V1  , If you ever get into a situation where Selected Value and the Options shown to the User in the drop down have to be different. There is a Props called valueRenderer.

valueRenderer : function which returns a custom way to render the value selected.
its signature is function (option) { return option.value //add any logic to derive the displayed text to user here }

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/tree/v1.x

Answer (score 0):

For Multi Value with typescript & react-select 5.7.x:

```
import Select, { components, MultiValueGenericProps } from "react-select";

type OptionType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
};

const OptionsArraySample = [
  {
    name: "test",
    id: "1",
    description: "test description",
  },
  {
    name: "test 2",
    id: "2",
    description: "test description 2",
  },
];

const MultiValueLabel = (props: MultiValueGenericProps<OptionType>) => {
  return <components.MultiValueLabel {...props}>{props.data.name}</components.MultiValueLabel>;
};

// Main Component

export default function FormComponent() {
  return (
    <form>
      <Select
        name="sampleSelect"
        className="react-select-container"
        classNamePrefix="react-select"
        components={{ MultiValueLabel }}
        isClearable={false}
        isSearchable={true}
        getOptionValue={(option) => option.id}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.name} ${option.description}`}
        isMulti={true}
        options={OptionsArraySample}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```