# react-select searchable element with input after selection

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-dom

so I am having a bit of a struggle working with react-select. My goal is to have a searchable select element, but when an option is selected I need to add some more letters/numbers to it. For example I choose option with label '+372', then i need to add more numbers to it and have that as my final value. I was wondering if that is even possible with react-select.

Here is some of the code https://pwl4jj0qoq.codesandbox.io/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-select - Show different text/label for drop-down and Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482985/react-select-show-different-text-label-for-drop-down-and-control)

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance what final value should be displayed I recommend you to use some technique as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482985/react-select-show-different-text-label-for-drop-down-and-control/52484756#52484756).

In summary you can change your options for something like this:

```
const options = [
  {
    label:
      "+372",
    // you can name this new prop has you want
    chipLabel: "+372000",
    value: "37200"
  },
  {
    label:
      "+373",
    chipLabel: "+37300",
    value: "37300"
  },
  {
    label:
      "+374,
    chipLabel: "+37400",
    value: "37400"
  }
];
```

and then override the component that display the selected option:

```
const SingleValue = props => (
  <components.SingleValue {...props}>
    {props.data.chipLabel}
  </components.SingleValue>
);

<Select options={options} components={{ SingleValue }} />
```

Live example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5w60l5qmx).